# Parsing an Angular application using MSHTML

Tags: angular, selenium, dom, selenium-chromedriver, mshtml

I am working on a project that parses the DOM of an Angular based page and outputs page object model classes that can be used with Selenium, using the following steps (using the Selenium Chrome driver):

1. Get raw HTML text [ Driver.FindElementByTagName("body").GetAttribute("outerHTML") ]
2. Create IHTMLDocument2 object
3. Write the text to the IHTMLDocument2 object [ doc.Write(text) ]
4. Recursively walk the DOM starting at the root element by passing the root element to a custom function PopulateChildren(IHTMLElement parent)
5. Within PopulateChildren, loop through parent.children passing each to PopulateChildren.

My problem is that while I can see the `<APP>` node in the "Elements" tab in the developer tools in Chrome, and see that it is a child of `<body>` and itself  has children, when it is the parent element in my code, it has no children.  Instead, it's child element(s) are all hanging off of the `<body>` element.

In Chrome I see the following DOM tree (excluding all script tags):

```
body
 └app
   ├main-layout-header
   │ └div
   ├div
   └div
```

When I walk the DOM in code I get this:

```
body
 ├app
 ├main-layout-header
 ├div
 ├div
 └div
```

The elements are there, just not in the right place.  It seems like MSHTML doesn't know what to do with any non-standard HTML elements.  They show up as base type HTMLElementUnknownClass.

Any ideas as to why it can't place them in the correct location?  I can probably code around this, but I'd really like to understand what's happening under the covers.

Comment: Some clarification.  When I output the text created in Step 1 in the IDE, I see the same DOM structure I see in Chrome.  It seems to be that the writing of unknown elements to a DOM object is where this is failing.

Comment: So you are attempting to automate the application or perform tasks as a user would?